# How to increase search speed from external API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, last.fm

How can I speed the search results generated from pinging the Lastfm api?

Here is the code we're working with:

```
def self.search(term)
    LastfmAPI.artist_search(term).map { |a| Lastfm::Artist.new(a) }
  end

  # Name and lastfm_id are synonyms                                                                                                                           
  def name
    self.lastfm_id
  end

  def past_events(geo=nil, options={})
    events = self.events.past
    lastfm_count = LastfmAPI.artist_getPastEvents_count(self.lastfm_id)

    # Check if database is current                                                                                                                            
    if events.count == lastfm_count # TODO: && the first event itself matches entirely                                                                        
      # TODO: extract above comparison to method                                                                                                              

      # return only those in the correct radius                                                                                                               
      events = events.in_radius(geo) if geo.present?
    else
      # if not current, make array of Lastfm::Event objects from API call                                                                                     
      events = LastfmAPI.artist_getPastEvents_all(self.lastfm_id, lastfm_count).map do |e|
    Saver::Events.perform_async(e) # send to worker to save to database                                                                                   

    Lastfm::Event.new(e)
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're depending on external services there is not much that you can do to speed up the actual execution of their service.  The best you can do is to cache things locally in your own app so that you're not making the round trip as often.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't up-vote as I don't have a 15 rep yet. But your response is appreciated Jeremy. We are currently caching the data, so search results improve as more data is cached locally. But new searches are still relatively slow and I guess this is beyond our control.